# Binary Operation and group

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Prove that $\oplus$ is a Binary operation on the set $Z_5= ( \bar{0},\bar{1},\bar{2},\bar{3},\bar{4})$ and $(Z_5,\oplus)$ is a group.

My thoughts: To be a binary relation it has to be a function. So now to prove it to be a function:

1) $\forall \ \bar{a} \ ,  \bar{b} \in \ Z_5 \rightarrow \bar{a}+\bar{b}=\overline{a+b}$

2) $\forall \ \bar{a} ,  \bar{b} ,\bar{c},\bar{d}\in \ Z_5,\  \bar{a}=\bar{b} \ and \ \bar{c}=\bar{d}\rightarrow \bar{a}\oplus\bar{c}=\bar{b}\oplus\bar{d} $

I think these are the conditions to be a function and hence a binary relation. but I don't understand how can I prove it.

Now to be a group

1) $\forall \ \bar{a} ,  \bar{b} ,\bar{c}\in \ Z_5 \rightarrow  \bar{a}\oplus(\bar{b} \oplus\bar{c})=\bar{a}\oplus (\overline{b+ c})=\overline{a+ (b+ c)}=(\overline{a+ b})\oplus\bar{c}=(\bar{a}\oplus\bar{b}) \oplus\bar{c} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $Is it correct?

2) $\forall \ \bar{a}\in  Z_5 \ \exists \  \bar{e} \rightarrow \bar{a}\oplus \bar{e}=\bar{e}\oplus \bar{a}=\bar{a} \ $ (I don't know how to prove it)

3) $\forall \ \bar{a}\in  Z_5 \ \exists \  \bar{i}\rightarrow \bar{a}\oplus \bar{i}=\bar{i}\oplus \bar{a}=\bar{e} \ $ (I don't know how to prove it)

Can someone help me please?

Comment: Here, I think, it pays to be very careful to avoid mixups. If you are using the notation that $a$ is an integer and $\bar a$ is its congruency class in $\Bbb Z_5$, then note that $\overline{a\oplus b}$ makes no sense, since $\oplus$ is not something you put between two integers. Write $\overline{a+b}$ instead. Similarily, $\bar a + \bar b$ makes no sense. Be clear on what entities are integers and what entities are congruency classes, and which operations apply to which.

Comment: For instance, the proof for associativity should be
$$
\bar a \oplus(\bar b \oplus \bar c) = \bar a \oplus \overline{(b + c)}\\ = \overline{a + (b+c)}\\ = \overline{(a+b)+c}\\ = \overline{(a+b)}\oplus \bar c\\=(\bar a \oplus \bar b)\oplus \bar c
$$where we on each line use either the definition $\bar a \oplus \bar b = \overline{a + b}$ or the well-known fact that addition on the integers is associative.

Comment: @Arthur Yes you are right, I have edited my statement.

Comment: Could you please give any hint about 2nd or 3rd statement?